# deploy RIA with BitNami Studio

Tags: deployment, web-deployment, bitnami, hhvm

I'm looking to deploy with native installers a RIA (rich internet application php + sencha) with BitNami!
When is Bitnami Studio going to be available?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami developer here,

BitNami Studio was never released, but you can use Bitnami Cloud Hosting to launch a server in AWS with the requirements that you need.

Also, we have a guide that explains how to deploy a custom PHP application on top of the Bitnami LAMP/WAMP/MAMP Stack. It can be useful for you
https://wiki.bitnami.com/Applications/BitNami_Custom_PHP_application

I hope it helps,

Regards,

Fran